# Dexterity RelationChoice Source Path Customization

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a RelationList field for Dexterity Type `Info` to relate with another Type `Venue` :

```
venue = RelationList(
    title=_(u'Venue'),
    value_type=RelationChoice(
        source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
            object_provides=IVenue.__identifier__,
        ),
    ),
    required=False,
)
```

`Venue` items are created in a specific folder, /info, how can I make browsing directly starting from the `/info folder`, instead of from the `/ folder` ?

[image]

My instance now runs on Plone 4.2.4 and plone.app.dexterity 1.2.1.

Comment: I find a related discussion 3 years ago: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/dexterity-development/AU4BXIHttao/AtFdNvO71lsJ

But anyone can hint what is the best practice for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

To limit the path of the `ObjPathSourceBinder` one could do the following:

```
[...]
source=ObjPathSourceBinder(navigtion_tree_query = {
    "object_provides":"IVenue.__identifier__",
    "path": {"query":"/my/path" }
    }
 ),
```

or you could just add a "path" argument to your code:

```
[...]
source=ObjPathSourceBinder(
    object_provides,IVenue.__identifier__,
    path={"query":"/mysite/media"},
),
```

The `navigation_tree_query` argument ist described [here:](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.formwidget.contenttree)